# Dynamic video creation using multiple images

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, html5-video

I want to create a user video which should take a photo album as input and play exactly like Facbook Look back video.

I have looked at couple of option including imagemagick and ffmpeg. Are there any good alternatives available for doing this.

Comment: Do you have an example of one of these videos for those of us who are not Facebook users?

Comment: I am not sure as such, we saw it on facebook and liked it and hence wanted to implement for our self.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a video dynamically through the browser you cannot do this on *client* side (not in a convenient way anyways). There is no functionality in browsers today that allows you to create video files (only streams) and the option is to write JavaScript code to do all the low-level encoding etc. which will take ages (to write but also in processing) and be prone to errors etc.

Your best option is to send the individual frames to server as for example jpeg (or png if you need high quality) and process it there using jobs where the processing can be done with f.ex. FFMpeg (which is great for these things).

Track the job id using some sort of user id and have a database or file updated with current status so the user can come back and check.